# How to translate special characters in a string in a Flutter application? Example: "DÃ©jÃ Vu" to "Déjà Vu"

Tags: flutter, dart, special-characters

I am new to Flutter development and I am trying to decode or translate special characters.
The example I am working with looks like this presented as normal text in flutter:

```
Example: "DÃ©jÃ Vu" to "Déjà Vu"
```

The left is how it appears on the UI and the result I would like to see is on the right.

I have tried using `Runes` class via docs --> https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/Runes-class.html but no luck.

This is the non-working code:

```
child: Text(new Runes("DÃ©jÃ Vu").string)
```

Update:I tried to pass `'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` in the API call, however it didn't seem to correct this particular issue. I will attach a snapshot of the response (I ran it with the new headers and also without[image])

Here is the code:

```
   Future<http.Response> _attemptCall(String suffix) => http.get(
        '$kBaseURL$suffix',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $_accessToken',
          'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        },
      );

  Future<T> _authorizedCall<T>(
    String suffix,
    T Function(String) decode,
  ) async {
    if (_accessToken == '') {
      await refreshToken();
    }
    http.Response response = await _attemptCall(suffix);

    var resBody = response.body;
    print('This is the response --> $resBody');
    if (response.statusCode == 401) {
      await refreshToken();
      response = await _attemptCall(suffix);
    }

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return decode(response.body);
    }
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Future<Episode> getEpisodeDetails(String id) => _authorizedCall(
        _episodeDetailUrl(id),
        (s) => Episode.fromJson(jsonDecode(s)),
      );
```

Comment: How do you get "DÃ©jÃ" in the first place? I think you try to read Déjà as a string of chars (1byte) instead of string of utf8 chars (up to 4 bytes) and you get the following output. You don't want to translate it to `Déjà`, what you want to do is accurately capture your utf8 string in the first place. Ã is a valid character, there is no way to translate it to another valid utf8 character

Comment: Good question - this is exactly how it's coming back from the API call. I will look into the API and see if they are correctly passing us the string.

Comment: You need to add json utf8 encode in the request

Comment: By the way, I learned a few years ago that the term for this charset-mangling is "Mojibake" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake.  This is a nice keyword on which to search further solutions.

Comment: Very interesting, I will add it to the answer, thanks Randal!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This charset mangling is called [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) (Thanks Randal Schwartz for pointing out!)

You cannot change "DÃ©jÃ Vu" back to "Déjà Vu", you have to take action on either the way data is encoded and sent or the way you decode the response.

See the binary representation of these utf-8 characters:

```
11000011 10000011 Ã   --> there is no way to tell `Ã` that it should be `à`
11000010 10101001 ©

11000011 10100000 à
11000011 10101001 é
```

You need to fix the problem upstream with the either the API response:

```
Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

The API is sending you back a stream of bytes, and should be utf8 in order to avoid this kind of output.

Or the way you decode the stream of bytes, you may also change:

```
return decode(response.body)
```

To

```
return decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
```

Comment: Okay I will try this solution and comeback to approve if it fixes my issue. 
Would the ``Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8`` look like this? 
 headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $_accessToken',
          'Content-type': 'application/json charset=utf-8',
        },

Comment: Exactly, it should look like this, perhaps with ';' in between

Comment: It appears to be doing no translation when I add that header. I will update my question with more code.

Comment: The API should also encode as utf8, not only your request

Comment: Okay so the Backend API needs to be looked at then it sounds like... which I don't have access to the BE code. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: Change the return of the response also, see my edit

Comment: This is what eventually worked for me --> ``return decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));`` if you want to update your answer

Answer (score 0):

The request call from Flutter looks like:

```
final response = await http.get(url, headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ${globals.postillaToken}',
  }).timeout(Duration(seconds: 5));
return Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);
```

The API itself looks like:

```
return Response({
        'status': True,
        'message': 'Get all UserDayOff from user',
        'data': serializer.data
    }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, content_type='application/json; charset=utf-8')
```

Having defined the encoding on both sides solved my problem.